# Can't create project or add ssh key on Gitlab

Tags: centos, gitolite, gitlab

I just created a CentOS 6.3 VM and followed these instructions for the gitlab install: http://howto.basjes.nl/linux/installing-gitlab-on-centos-6

I've tried this installation with both gitlab v3.01 and v2.91.

Here is what is working for me:

- I can complete the gitlab install without problem
- From the command-line, I can use passwordless authentication from the the gitlab service account to the gitolite service account
- From the command-line, I can clone the gitolite-admin repo, make changes, and pushes the changes back to the remote repo
- I can start the rails web app
- I can login the web management site
- I can create new accounts and login with the new accounts

Here's what I can't do:

- I can't create projects (Repos)
- I can't add ssh keys

I always get the same error:

> *GitLab was unable to access your Gitolite system.*

In the `githost.log` log file, I get a less than useful error:

> *ERROR -> Timeout::Error execution expired*

- I've double checked permissions
- Reviewed the `gitlab.yml` config file
- Ran through the four suggested troubleshooting tips from the web page
- Tried different versions of gitlab, but no matter what I do, I keep getting the same error.

I'm stuck because the logs don't tell me anything and I am able to access the gitolite repositories with the gitlab service account without issue.  Anybody have any success with the most recent versions of CentOS/Gitlab/Gitolite? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late - but for completeness.

I've run into the same problem doing installation on recent Debian version.
It is, or was for me, caused by an old version of redis-server.